# Closing alert dialog after onClick from extended activity

Tags: java, android, dialog, onclick, android-alertdialog

In my main activity I have an alert dialog which creates a new intent when clicked. When the alert dialog is clicked and the new activity is opened I cannot dismiss the alert dialog even though I have included dialog.cancel(); in my main activity code.

Dialog builder (Main activity)

```
final Builder alertDialogBuilder = new Builder(this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Navigation");
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Go to the new activity.");
      alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Okay", new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Log.d(TAG, "$$ onClick");
              dialog.cancel();
              Intent newactivity = new Intent(MAINACTIVITY.this,NEWACTIVITY.class);
              startActivity(newactivity);
          }
      });
      alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

After I click on the "Okay" button the dialog closes, but when the new activity is loaded the dialog reappears. The new activity extends the activity that the dialog is created in (Main activity).

Is there a way that I can close the alert dialog from the new extended activity?

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       Log.d(TAG, "$$ onClick");

          Intent newactivity = new Intent(MAINACTIVITY.this,NEWACTIVITY.class);
          startActivity(newactivity);
          dialog.cancel();
      }
  });
  alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I replaced my code with what you provided and the same problem is happening. I want the dialog to not extend the activity. I need other strings to extend the activity, but I need to prevent the dialog from extending.